# How do I use the REST API to update an Apex Trigger?

Tags: apex, javascript, api, rest, contact

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://ap17.salesforce.com/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger/01q2x000000YiNcAAK' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer 00D2....' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Name": "ContactCreateUpdateDeleteApexTrigger",
    "TableEnumOrId": "Contact",
    "Body":"trigger ContactCreateUpdateDeleteApexTrigger on Contact (after update,after insert, after delete) {            String url = '\''https:endpoint.com'\'';         String content = WebhookClass.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old,'\''Contact'\'');         WebhookClass.callout(url, content);          }"
    }'
```

I am trying to update an existing apex trigger from rest api however the existing trigger is not updated

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No I am getting 200 response @SanderdeJong

Comment: Although Apex classes and triggers have the Create and Update field properties, a runtime exception occurs if you try to create or update them using the API. Instead, use the Ant Migration Tool, the Salesforce user interface, or the Salesforce Extensions for Visual Studio Code to create or update Apex classes or triggers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update triggers using the sObject API, as it is not an sObject. You need to use a [metadata deployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deploy.htm). Most people today prefer to use [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/platform/dx), as it is the newest modern tool for deployments, and can deploy from the command line.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox I went through the documentation I am still unable my trigger, not sure what I am missing. Could you help me with a curl ?

Comment: @ChrisBlesson You need to create a ZIP file and then deploy it. The URL for this would be on the API endpoint using POST to `/services/data/v49.0/metadata/deployRequest`. You'll need to read the documentation. I don't use curl regularly, you'll need to use the documentation.

Comment: Thank you @sfdcfox

Comment: @ChrisBlesson did you manage to do this? Any example or doc that could point me in the right direction to create a trigger on new Case? Thanks in advance

Comment: @hosseio As I stated, you need a mdapi deployment. What are you trying to do? How can we help?

Comment: @ChrisBlesson thanks for your reply man. What I want to do is to create a trigger for when a new Case is created, and call to a different API with this Case information. I am reading at the metadata api and apextrigger for the moment, to try to figure this out.

Comment: @hosseio it sounds like you need a callout, not a metadata API call. How about this? Why don't you ask a new question, include as much detail as you can, and I'll take a look at it for you.

Comment: yes for sure. I was just asking because it sounded similar to me. Thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: @hosseio are trying to apex triggers directly via REST API or did you handle this via any other method ? Cause I figured out a way to update triggers. Let me know if you still need help?